# Reading soft file data to R from a downloaded file

Tags: r

I've been download soft file data from GSE47875 assertion number to my labtop. Now I want to load it to R, i've been used the

```
getGEO("GSE47875",filename = "Desktop/GSE47875/GSE47875_series_matrix.txt.gz")
```

command but I faced the following error:

```
sh: 1: curl: not found
File stored at: 
/tmp/RtmpHyQAgg/GPL1355.soft
Error in file(fname, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(myurl, destfile, mode = mode, quiet = TRUE, method = getOption("download.file.method.GEOquery")) :
  download had nonzero exit status
2: In file(fname, "r") :
  cannot open file '/tmp/RtmpHyQAgg/GPL1355.soft': No such file or directory
```

Where is the problem? How can load the soft file data to R?

Comment: Problem related to curl, it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're on Linux, and `curl` (a program for downloading from the command line or scripts) isn't installed. It's free, so install it! You can install it on Debian-type distros with `sudo apt-get install curl`.

[This post](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/18301-Bioconductor-Error-message-using-GEOquery-package?p=139700&viewfull=1#post139700) has some more detail.